# Why is auto verify failing for Android App Links

Tags: android, android-app-links

We are trying to get Android App Links working on our app but we are hitting problems with the Auto Verify step.

We have our assetlinks.json file deployed on our server and it checks out with all Googles verification tools, however the verification fails on the device.

The output from logcat isn't particularly helpful as it just says an error has occurred.

[image]

Can anyone give us any pointers on what the issue could be?

Answer (score 0):

I faced similar issue when I started implementing App links. I think it may take some times to be up and running, as I did not do anything else and few hours later it the verification worked.

edit: could you post your android.manifest please?